# php multi array from html name

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have few select options with same name like this:

```
<select class="form-control b2roker-basic-single" name="api[]">
//php loop
</select>
<select class="form-control afp-basic-multiple" name="afp[]" multiple="multiple">
//php loop
</select>
<select class="form-control b2roker-basic-single" name="api[]">
//php loop
</select>
<select class="form-control afp-basic-multiple" name="afp[]" multiple="multiple">
//php loop
</select>
<select class="form-control b2roker-basic-single" name="api[]">
//php loop
</select>
<select class="form-control afp-basic-multiple" name="afp[]" multiple="multiple">
//php loop
</select>
```

The afp is a multi selector so it can contain a few options in one select tag.

I am trying to make an array from it, my array needs to bee like this:

```
[api_id] => [afp_ids]
```

Here is an example:

```
 $x = [
    [98] => [1,5,6],
    [89] => [5,8,6],

    ];
```

Its my third day that I am trying to find the solution for this :)

Comment: post output of 
print_r($_POST['api']); exit;

Comment: Well, there are no correlation between the two selects in HTML. You would need to rethink how you output the HTML first of all. What you have now are two arrays, the `api` and the `afp` and there is no correlation between them, neither in PHP nor in HTML.

Comment: Can you modify HTML, give slightly different names to select boxes?

Comment: No because its a multi chose, the user can chose only one api or a few api with a few afp